# Codeigniter - Check if a value from array exists in database not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table called user where I have a column called `sub_teams`. I have stored values in there like `Construction,Teamwork,Website` etc.

I have an announcement table called announcements where I have a body column and a `sub_teams` column.

All values in both `sub_teams` column in the `users` and the `announcements` has values stored separated by commas. What I want to achieve is that if an announcement has `Construction,Website` in one of the rows and the user has `Website,Teamwork` then he is able to view the announcement since he is in the `Construction` sub_team. **Edit**: But I want to display all rows of announcements that have the `sub_teams` not just one.

How can I achieve this? I have tried this:

```
    $uid = $this->session->userdata('uid');
    $this->db->select('sub_teams');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('uid', $uid);
    $sub_teams_query = $this->db->get();
    $sub_teams_result = $sub_teams_query->row();
    $sub_teams = explode(',', $sub_teams_result->sub_teams);

    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('announcements');
    $this->db->where('active', 1);
    $this->db->where('date_created <', date('Y-m-d H:m:s')); //hide the announcements that are new and not published yet.

    foreach ($sub_teams as $sub_team) {
        $this->db->or_like('view_sub_teams', $sub_team);
    }


    $this->db->join('users', 'users.uid = announcements.uid');
    $this->db->order_by('date_created', 'desc', 'after');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

It seems to not work as it displays every single announcement. Thanks guys.

Comment: you want to fetch announcements for particular user?? or for all users??

Comment: print the query and try to run in phpmyadmin. It may help to report the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If im not wrong, you are fetching announcements for a particular user. Its returning all rows because in second query, you have missed `where` for `userId` condition

```
$this->db->where('uid', $uid);
```

Add the where condition in your second query.

Comment: Then what about this line `$this->db->join('users', 'users.uid = announcements.uid');
`

Comment: @Saty, it will get result for all matching users.

Comment: Here OP also use `uid`. As per your answer you suggest OP to change `uid` with column name

Comment: you are asking the column name??

Comment: Yes `uid` is also use here `users.uid = announcements.uid` then what about this???

Comment: ok ok... i was thinking that `where` is wrong. Thanks you for correction:)

Comment: Unfortunately, the announcement table doesn't have the `uid` column, it only has the `sub_teams` column and I'm trying to display only the announcements that have the sub_teams that the user is in. Sorry for being confusing and I hope that make sense.

Comment: `$this->db->join('users', 'users.uid = announcements.uid');`, then how come you are using uid from announcement table??

Comment: @TaylorSwift did u try adding the where condition??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju The uid is the user who created teh announcement. I'm getting the user details of the person who created it

Comment: What is the problem now?? same issue??

Comment: Yes, still problem. This code works but only works in an order. For instance, if the user is assigned "Programming,Construction" then he will see all assigned that are shared with either Programming or Construction. This is good so far. The problem happens when the values of sub_teams in the user's table is not in order. It won't show me announcements that are either Programming or Construction if the order is "Construction,Programming".

Comment: use order by clause to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93616/discussion-between-taylor-swift-and-niranjan-n-raju).